# Migration from Flyway 1.x - rollback consideration

Tags: flyway

I am currently using Flyway version 1.7. I read in the [release notes](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/releaseNotes.html) that Flyway 2.0 comes with a new metadata table format and all 2.x versions do an automatic upgrade on first run. All fine so far. But what if I have to rollback my application and downgrade Flyway back to 1.7? Will the old Flyway work with the new metadata format? Is there a rollback script to get the old metadata table format back?

I am using PostgreSQL as database engine.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a one-way upgrade. It does run within a transaction though, so in the very unlikely event it would fail, the transaction would be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understand that Flyway is upgrade only. But part of our deployment plans is always how to rollback to previous version using downgrade scripts (manually). Backup restore only used in worst-case scenario. So my question really; how can I manually downgrade metadata format?